# PyGTK, how can I lock a window so it cannot be resized?

Tags: python, gtk, window, pygtk, resizable

I am looking for a way to lock the window. I found `window.set_resizable(False)`, but that resizes the window to its requested size and *then* locks it. I would like to be able to resize my window, and then lock it into the size I have resized it to.

Comment: Think thrice whether locking window size is a good idea.  In 99% percent of the cases, there will be a case that makes some users really hate you for it.

Comment: Yeah, I know. The program I'm making includes a timer that is precise to the hundredth. I found out that GTK/Pango throws a huge fit when you try to resize a window with a label updating 100 times per second. ;) All I'm doing is locking the window while the timer is running, so it's all good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could `set_size_request()` with the current window size (from `window_get_size()`) before you call `set_resizable()`?

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought of that! Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

window.set_geometry_hints(window, min_width, min_height, max_width, max_height)